# Static and crackling sound coming from speakers in 19.04

Tags: sound

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu 19.04 and my speakers have been constantly making a static noise with crackling. I didn't have this issue in 18.10. The static sound goes away for a second when I change the volume and there is no sound when I completely mute the audio.