# Sound Cracking and Popping Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 19.04

I have spent a lot of time searching the web for an solution but nothing seems to work. I tried these fixes

[Static and crackling sound coming from speakers in 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135492/static-and-crackling-sound-coming-from-speakers-in-19-04)

[Cracking and popping sound from left side of headphone on Front Left/Right sound test](https://askubuntu.com/questions/910221/cracking-and-popping-sound-from-left-side-of-headphone-on-front-left-right-sound)

and the pulse-audio fix but nothing worked.

My Speakers just randomly crack and make noises when doing nothing and sometimes while playing back audio. I haven't had that Problem before and when i boot into windows everything is fine. So i can rule out a Hardware problem.

I got the Z370 AORUS Gaming 5 (rev. 1.0) with the Realtek® ALC1220 codec. Connected is an 5.1 Surround system made by Logitech.

The Problem was already there in 18.04 and Upgrading to 19 did nothing to fix it.

I just tried connecting and then switching to my external soundblaster card but staying connected to the mobo headers and the noises continues

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04 - cracking sound from left speaker that occurs mainly before the playback of video/audio.
This solution from James Kelly works for me:

*if your distro uses alsa you should be able to fix the issue directly by modifying the following conf file: /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf*

*Open file in console using:*

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

*Add the following line to the end of the file:*

```
options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N
```

*Hit Ctrl-S then Ctrl-X*

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pdmy8dMWitg&lc=UgwSJTT-VsjsaAzzGk54AaABAg

Comment: And you have to restart the maschine after that (or just alsa).

Comment: Wow... +1...  thanks, this has been bugging me for ages!

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230833/annoying-click-popping-sound-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesnt work for me :(