# 5 seconds after no audio - my speaker turns off

Tags: sound, speakers

I never had this issue on Windows 10 and I just switched to Ubuntu.

When there is no audio playing, after 5 seconds my speaker acts like if I  pulled of the aux cable out the speaker(it hums),

But the moment that I turn on any audio, speaker continues working normally. 
Even pressing the volume shortcuts(volume up or down) on my keyboard does the trick because it plays the short sound.

Edit for more info:
Just installed and updated the Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

I am using my motherboard audio jack, in settings it recognizes it as a Line Out - HD-Audio Generic
And as a ghetto fix, i can open Youtube video and simply mute it, even though there is no sound playing. So, it doesnt matter if there is any sound it just needs something that should be playing audio?

Edit 2: No, I have not installed any sound related programs or anything it is like this out of the box, and no, rebooting does not fix the issue.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This odd behaviour can sometimes happen because of a feature they introduced in more recent versions of Ubuntu where it turns off the Intel HD Audio device after a few minutes of non-use to save battery. The downside is that popping noise you might experience a short while after audio has been inactive.

I had this same problem, and found the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135492/static-and-crackling-sound-coming-from-speakers-in-19-04/1135589#1135589).

To circumvent it, open this file as root `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

And add to the bottom of it:

```
options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N
```