# Distorted / crackling audio: Ubuntu 19.10 on MacBook 7.1, 2010

Tags: nvidia, sound, macbook, 19.10

I have installed Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) on a MacBook 7,1, Mid-2010, [A1342](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.4-white-13-polycarbonate-unibody-mid-2010-specs.html). Unfortunately (unlike Ubuntu 19.04), the audio is not working properly, it's very choppy and distorted.

inxi -A :

```
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA MCP89 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.3.0-19-generic
```

lspci -nnk :

```
00:08.0 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 High Definition Audio [10de:0d94] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation MCP89 High Definition Audio [10de:cb89]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

aplay -l :

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 0: CS4206 Analog [CS4206 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 1: CS4206 Digital [CS4206 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

inxi -F :

```
System:
  Host: MacBook7.1 Kernel: 5.3.0-19-generic x86_64 bits: 64 
  Desktop: Gnome 3.34.1 Distro: Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan Ermine) 
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Apple product: MacBook7,1 v: 1.0 
  Mobo: Apple model: Mac-F22C89C8 date: 06/01/10 
CPU:
  Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core2 Duo P8600 bits: 64 type: MCP 
  L2 cache: 3072 KiB 
  Speed: 796 MHz min/max: 798/2394 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 796 2: 796 
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA MCP89 [GeForce 320M] driver: nouveau v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.5 driver: nouveau 
  resolution: 1280x800~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: NVAF v: 3.3 Mesa 19.2.1
```

pacmd info :

```
Memory blocks currently allocated: 2, size: 113,8 KiB.
Memory blocks allocated during the whole lifetime: 30879, size: 50,1 MiB.
Memory blocks imported from other processes: 0, size: 0 B.
Memory blocks exported to other processes: 0, size: 0 B.
Total sample cache size: 49,9 KiB.
Default sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
Default channel map: front-left,front-right
Default sink name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_08.0.analog-stereo
Default source name: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_08.0.analog-stereo.monitor
Memory blocks of type POOL: 2 allocated/14605 accumulated.
Memory blocks of type POOL_EXTERNAL: 0 allocated/310 accumulated.
Memory blocks of type APPENDED: 0 allocated/0 accumulated.
Memory blocks of type USER: 0 allocated/0 accumulated.
Memory blocks of type FIXED: 0 allocated/13130 accumulated.
Memory blocks of type IMPORTED: 0 allocated/3144 accumulated.
25 module(s) loaded.
    index: 0
    name: <module-device-restore>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore the volume/mute state of devices"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 1
    name: <module-stream-restore>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore the volume/mute/device state of streams"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 2
    name: <module-card-restore>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore profile of cards"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 3
    name: <module-augment-properties>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Augment the property sets of streams with additional static information"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 4
    name: <module-switch-on-port-available>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "David Henningsson"
        module.description = "Switches ports and profiles when devices are plugged/unplugged"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 5
    name: <module-switch-on-connect>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Michael Terry"
        module.description = "When a sink/source is added, switch to it or conditionally switch to it"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 6
    name: <module-udev-detect>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Detect available audio hardware and load matching drivers"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 7
    name: <module-alsa-card>
    argument: <device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_08.0" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_08.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1">
    used: 0
    load once: no
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "ALSA Card"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 8
    name: <module-bluetooth-policy>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Frédéric Dalleau, Pali Rohár"
        module.description = "Policy module to make using bluetooth devices out-of-the-box easier"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 9
    name: <module-bluetooth-discover>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"
        module.description = "Detect available Bluetooth daemon and load the corresponding discovery module"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 10
    name: <module-bluez5-discover>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "João Paulo Rechi Vita"
        module.description = "Detect available BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio devices and load BlueZ 5 Bluetooth audio drivers"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 11
    name: <module-native-protocol-unix>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: no
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Native protocol (UNIX sockets)"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 12
    name: <module-default-device-restore>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically restore the default sink and source"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 13
    name: <module-rescue-streams>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "When a sink/source is removed, try to move its streams to the default sink/source"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 14
    name: <module-always-sink>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
        module.description = "Always keeps at least one sink loaded even if it's a null one"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 15
    name: <module-intended-roles>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Automatically set device of streams based on intended roles of devices"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 16
    name: <module-suspend-on-idle>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "When a sink/source is idle for too long, suspend it"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 17
    name: <module-console-kit>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Create a client for each ConsoleKit session of this user"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 18
    name: <module-systemd-login>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Create a client for each login session of this user"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 19
    name: <module-position-event-sounds>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Position event sounds between L and R depending on the position on screen of the widget triggering them."
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 20
    name: <module-role-cork>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Mute & cork streams with certain roles while others exist"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 21
    name: <module-snap-policy>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Canonical Ltd"
        module.description = "Ubuntu Snap policy management"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 22
    name: <module-filter-heuristics>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
        module.description = "Detect when various filters are desirable"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 23
    name: <module-filter-apply>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: yes
    properties:
        module.author = "Colin Guthrie"
        module.description = "Load filter sinks automatically when needed"
        module.version = "13.0"
    index: 24
    name: <module-cli-protocol-unix>
    argument: <>
    used: -1
    load once: no
    properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "Command line interface protocol (UNIX sockets)"
        module.version = "13.0"
1 sink(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_08.0.analog-stereo>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 9039
    volume: front-left: 29115 /  44% / -21,14 dB,   front-right: 29115 /  44% / -21,14 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 52057 /  79% / -6,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max request: 0 KiB
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    monitor source: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 371,52 ms
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_08.0>
    module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "CS4206 Analog"
        alsa.id = "CS4206 Analog"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xd3280000 irq 23"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:08.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0d94"
        device.product.name = "MCP89 High Definition Audio"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "front:0"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "65536"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "32768"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        alsa.mixer_name = "Cirrus Logic CS4206"
        alsa.components = "HDA:10134206,106b1f00,00100301 HDA:10de000c,10de0101,00100200"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    ports:
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
    active port: <analog-output-speaker>
1 source(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_08.0.analog-stereo.monitor>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: SUSPENDED
    suspend cause: IDLE
    priority: 1030
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0,00 ms
    max rewind: 0 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 0,00 ms; range is 0,50 .. 371,52 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    card: 0 <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_08.0>
    module: 7
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xd3280000 irq 23"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:08.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0d94"
        device.product.name = "MCP89 High Definition Audio"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
11 client(s) logged in.
    index: 0
    driver: <module-systemd-login.c>
    owner module: 18
    properties:
        application.name = "Login Session 1"
        systemd-login.session = "1"
    index: 4
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 11
    properties:
        application.name = "GNOME Shell Volume Control"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.id = "org.gnome.VolumeControl"
        application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"
        application.version = "3.34.1"
        application.process.id = "1171"
        application.process.user = 
        application.process.host = 
        application.process.binary = "gnome-shell"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "3510375181dd40a892dccb932abb57ce"
    index: 5
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 11
    properties:
        application.name = "GNOME Volume Control Media Keys"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.id = "org.gnome.VolumeControl"
        application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"
        application.version = ""
        application.process.id = "1371"
        application.process.user = 
        application.process.host = 
        application.process.binary = "gsd-media-keys"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "3510375181dd40a892dccb932abb57ce"
    index: 7
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 11
    properties:
        application.name = "Firefox"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        window.x11.screen = "0"
        application.process.id = "2756"
        application.process.user = 
        application.process.host = 
        application.process.binary = "firefox"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        application.process.machine_id = "3510375181dd40a892dccb932abb57ce"
        application.icon_name = "firefox"
    index: 8
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 11
    properties:
        application.name = "Firefox"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.icon_name = "firefox"
        application.version = "69.0.3"
        application.process.id = "2756"
        application.process.user = 
        application.process.host = 
        application.process.binary = "firefox"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "3510375181dd40a892dccb932abb57ce"
    index: 9
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 11
    properties:
        application.name = "AudioIPC Server"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.process.id = "2756"
        application.process.user = 
        application.process.host = 
        application.process.binary = "firefox"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "3510375181dd40a892dccb932abb57ce"
        application.icon_name = "firefox"
    index: 10
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 11
    properties:
        application.name = "Terminal"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.icon_name = "org.gnome.Terminal"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        window.x11.screen = "0"
        application.process.id = "3166"
        application.process.user = 
        application.process.host =
        application.process.binary = "gnome-terminal-server"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        application.process.machine_id = "3510375181dd40a892dccb932abb57ce"
    index: 12
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 11
    properties:
        application.name = "GNOME Settings"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.id = "org.gnome.VolumeControl"
        application.icon_name = "multimedia-volume-control"
        application.version = ""
        application.process.id = "4207"
        application.process.user = 
        application.process.host = 
        application.process.binary = "gnome-control-center"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "3510375181dd40a892dccb932abb57ce"
    index: 13
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 11
    properties:
        application.name = "Settings"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        window.x11.screen = "0"
        application.process.id = "4207"
        application.process.user = 
        application.process.host = 
        application.process.binary = "gnome-control-center"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        application.process.machine_id = "3510375181dd40a892dccb932abb57ce"
        application.icon_name = "org.gnome.Settings"
    index: 14
    driver: <protocol-native.c>
    owner module: 11
    properties:
        application.name = "Mutter"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.process.id = "1171"
        application.process.user = 
        application.process.host = 
        application.process.binary = "gnome-shell"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "3510375181dd40a892dccb932abb57ce"
    index: 16
    driver: <cli.c>
    owner module: 24
    properties:
        application.name = "UNIX socket client"
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_08.0>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xd3280000 irq 23"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:08.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.0/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "0d94"
        device.product.name = "MCP89 High Definition Audio"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 65, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 6500, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 6565, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-21: Analog Surround 2.1 Output (priority 1300, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 2.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1365, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-40: Analog Surround 4.0 Output (priority 1200, available: unknown)
        output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 1265, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (priority 5500, available: unknown)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5565, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5900, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5965, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 865, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 800, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 865, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5765, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5765, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 665, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 665, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_08.0.analog-stereo/#0: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_08.0.analog-stereo.monitor/#0: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (priority 0, latency offset 0 usec, available: unknown)
            properties:

        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
0 sink input(s) available.
0 source output(s) available.
1 cache entrie(s) available.
    name: <bell-window-system>
    index: 0
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    length: 51048
    duration: 0,3 s
    volume: n/a
            balance 0,00
    lazy: no
    filename: <n/a>
    properties:
        media.role = "event"
        event.description = "Bell event"
        event.id = "bell-window-system"
        media.name = "bell-window-system"
        media.filename = "/usr/share//sounds/Yaru/stereo/bell.oga"
        application.name = "Mutter"
        native-protocol.peer = "UNIX socket client"
        native-protocol.version = "33"
        application.process.id = "1171"
        application.process.user = "Macbook"
        application.process.host = "MacBook"
        application.process.binary = "gnome-shell"
        application.language = "en_US.UTF-8"
        window.x11.display = ":0"
        application.process.machine_id = "3510375181dd40a892dccb932abb57ce"
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135492/static-and-crackling-sound-coming-from-speakers-in-19-04 That solved the problem for me on my desktop PC.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with the same Mac model.

The fact that it worked fine with 19.04 suggests that something may have happened between kernel 5.0 and kernel 5.3 (the one of 19.10).

Indeed, [this user](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/suddenly-distorted-crackled-audio-sound/97003/8) had the same problem just by updating the kernel from 4.19 to 5.2.

The bug was reported on [kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=204477), someone identified the [faulty commit](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/9b6f7e7a296e17990aae298c809b001e99ddd151), and a patch has been proposed.

So I guess either you recompile a 5.3 kernel with this patch or you install a 5.0 kernel ; or like I did you roll back to 19.04!