# No sound except popping noises on my HP AiO (Realtek ALC225) for all Linux distributions

Tags: sound, hp, realtek

After erasing disk and installing Ubuntu 19.10 on my HP Pavilion 24-xa0506nz, there is no more sound coming from the built-in B&O speakers, except loud popping noises on shutdown, reboot, youtube videos launch... Now I am using Ubuntu 19.10, but the same thing happened with the following installations : Ubuntu 18.04.3, Lubuntu 19.10, Kubuntu 19.10, Debian 10.1.0, Fedora 30, Fedora 31, Linux Mint 19.2, Manjaro 18.1.2 and openSUSE 15.1 (the sound was fine with Windows 10).

According to HP, the codec is Realtek ALC3259, but with the terminal I get

```
chris13@Pavilion:~$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
chris13@Pavilion:~$ cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC225
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI
```

I've been trying to solve this for two weeks, checking many things from different forums.
Following [Static and crackling sound coming from speakers in 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135492/static-and-crackling-sound-coming-from-speakers-in-19.04), I have added `options snd-hda-intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N`
to the file */etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf*:
now the popping noises occur only on shutdown and reboot.

I have also added to */etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf*
the line `options snd-hda-intel model=***`,
checking for *** any HP models in section 3.15 of https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/audio_intel_hda, but nothing worked.

Next, the line `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences audible-bell false` did not change anything about the popping noises on shutdown (see https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/9bs4tq/loud_popping_noise_on_shutdownreboot/).

I have tried to install the Realtek Linux driver (https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software), but it didn't work (mistakes after the command `make`).
I have also spent some time with alsamixer and pavucontrol, but i still have no sound except popping noises on shutdown/reboot.
Note that the only "regular" Linux sound that I have heard was a normal "beep" sound after starting the computer on my Debian bootable USB.

There must be something wrong about the linux configuration of the Realtek ALC225...

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I know someone who has exactly the same computer and exactly the same problem! Besides, adding `options snd-hda-intel model=alc225-wyse` to the file 
*/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf* did not change anything.

2nd Edit: I have created a bug report on Launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1852813

Comment: Maybe my separate post can help
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1200906/sound-ubuntu-linux-19-10-on-hp-pavilion-aio-not-working?noredirect=1#comment2013771_1200906

Comment: Yes it helps! As in your case, the sound of my HP AiO is OK only after a sleeping mode (I still have popping noises on shutdown, reboot, ...).

Comment: @Chris13 Did you manage to get a permanent solution for this, or do you still have to put the computer in sleep mode?

Comment: No, the situation hasn't changed. Thanks.