# Sound ubuntu linux 19.10 on hp pavilion aio not working

Tags: sound, alsa, hp

I have an HP Pavilion AIO with Ubuntu 19.10 and sound is not working.

It is exactly the same behaviour like in the thread
[No sound except popping noises on my HP AiO (Realtek ALC225) for all Linux distributions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186588/no-sound-except-popping-noises-on-my-hp-aio-realtek-alc225-for-all-linux-distr)

Unfortunately my comment was deleted since I am a newby here.

However I think I have a (ugly) solution:

- When I start Ubuntu from cold machine - it is not working.
  `sudo lsmod | grep -i snd` output: https://pastebin.com/7TyVcW6M
- When I suspend and restart from there - sound is working.
  `sudo lsmod | grep -i snd` output: https://pastebin.com/FFAP0U5j

Maybe that will help to solve the problem for the developers.

Comment: Maybe your drivers aren't loaded initially at boot and are subsequently

Comment: Reboot your system again and run `sudo lsmod | grep -i snd` and then suspend and wake from suspension and run that command again and compare to see if your drivers are getting loaded when the system boots

Comment: Loaded drivers are identical - but the order of the drivers shown is different - do not know if this makes really a difference.
-----------------------
diff snd_driver_coldstart.txt snd_driver_suspend.txt 
8d7
< snd_hda_codec_realtek   118784  1
10d8
< snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
12d9
< ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
19a17
> snd_hda_codec_realtek   118784  1
20a19
> snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
21a21
> ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek

Comment: Please add the two results to your question so we can compare

Comment: [snd driver coldstart](https://pastebin.com/7TyVcW6M)
[snd driver from suspend](https://pastebin.com/FFAP0U5j)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for referring to my post (it has just been updated). I confirm that the sound of my HP AiO is OK just after a sleeping mode !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem & went thru all processes. I just couldn't believe it's working after waking from sleep but not after a cold start.

I just add those 2 lines at the end of
/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:

```
#fix for hp-pavilion aio 27 xa0013ng
blacklist snd_hda_codec_realtek
```

After a reboot lsmod gives me this output:

```
lsmod|grep snd
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    77824  1 sof_pci_dev
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_byt      24576  1 sof_pci_dev
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof               102400  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc,sof_pci_dev
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 sof_pci_dev
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  3 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    32768  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,sof_pci_dev
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,sof_pci_dev
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_soc_core          241664  3 snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          49152  3
snd_intel_nhlt         20480  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         131072  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core           90112  8 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  9 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    90112  18   snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi 
soundcore            16384  1 snd
```

So no snd_hda_codec_realtek which causes the problems here.
And the best of all: Sound is working without any cracks - after returning from sleep mode AND after a cold start!
I tested it with Kernel 5.3.0-46-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP

I hope this will help to solve this annoying problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with no sound & annoying popping noise on a HP Pavilion 24-XA0070A using Ubuntu 22.04... I used vokke suggestion (above or below) & it fixed my problem.

Just add those 2 lines at the end of /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:

First Line = #fix for hp-pavilion aio 27 xa0013ng

Second Line = blacklist snd_hda_codec_realtek